# Laravel Import: How to import image from the excel file to server

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I want to access the image from excel and store the image on the server but when I try to get the image it returns null as no value in the cell.

[image: Example image]

The example image above. I can access the value from other cells but for the cell, image_path gets the value null.

Have referred to a few reference sites and tried the solutions but still have the same problem where the image value is null.

Reference

1. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#reading-images-from-a-worksheet
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-import-images-using-laravel-excel

Comment: show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Need to insert image into cell using Microsoft Excel then the code I refer from the listed reference above working. Previously insert image into cell by using WPS office.